# How to get only time value from Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below, `StartTime` is `05/29/2017 1:00:00 PM`.

But I want `StartTime` to be `1:00:00 PM`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>From</label>
     <input class="form-control " id="StartTime" type="text" name="StartTime"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
});
```

Comment: This code worked when i changed the data type of StartTime  from DateTime to String  into back-end.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can disable date

```
  $(function () { 
  $('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',

    });
});
```

Comment: datepicker:false is not working it shows following error in the console.
TypeError: option datepicker is not recognized!  bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1502:27

Comment: here is the jsfiddle of your working code https://jsfiddle.net/a2vwpod7/7/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#StartTime").datetimepicker({
           format: 'hh:ii',
           startView: 1,
           pickDate: false,
           autoclose: true 
        }).on("show", function(){
        $(".table-condensed .prev").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(".table-condensed .switch").text("Pick Time");
        $(".table-condensed .next").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

Comment: Don't know why datetimepicker pickDate, startView is not recognizing. I am using latest version of datetimepicker.